# Soft deleting using Mongoose not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to soft-delete items using the following Mongoose code:

```
// Remove a client
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  logger.info(`Removing Client ${req.params.clientId}`);
  Client.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.clientId },
    { active: false },
    { new: true }
  )
  .then(client => {
    logger.info('client: ', client);
    if (!client) {
      return res.sendStatus(404);
    }
    res.sendStatus(204);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    logger.error(err);
    res.status(422).send(err.errors);
  });
};
```

But for some reason the `active` flag just doesn't want to get set to `false`.  The log shows the clientId is being passed in, and the `then` code has the Client data, but the `active` flag still set to `true`.  Do I need to flush or commit somehow?

**Edit - Adding schema**

```
export const ClientSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      index: true,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  { collection: 'clients' }
);
```

Comment: What is the mongoose schema please?

Comment: Also turn on `mongoose.set('debug',true)` as it will at least show you exactly what is being issued to the server after the schema "has it's say". Odds are it's a schema mismatch and it does not know what "active" is, so it gets removed.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT: That was it...I forgot to add `active` to the schema.  I updated the post, but if you can put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: findByIdAndUpdate takes a string or ObjectId as first parameter, the point of the ID functions is convenience, otherwise you might as well call findOneAndUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comment.

You have forgotten to add `active` field into the mongoose schema.